# Continuous but not compact Sobolev embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open ball and $p^* = \frac{pn}{n-p}$ be the Sobolev conjugate. Show that, for $p=2$, $W^{1,p}(U)$ cannot be compactly embedded in $L^{p^*}(U)$.

Now, from the Sobolev inequality, for bounded $U$, we have that $$\|u\|_{L^{p^*}(U)} \leq C\ \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}$$ for $1 \leq p < n$ and $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$. That means that $W^{1,2}(U)$ is continuously embedded in ${L^{p^*}(U)}$, so to prove the above claim we would need to show that a bounded sequence in $W^{1,2}(U)$ is **not** precompact in ${L^{p^*}(U)}$.

That is the point that I am missing, how do I proceed with this? Do I need a counterexample or a proof? I am missing the intuition of what's happening and I cannot get it started. Any hint would be appreciated.

Also, there is no mention of boundedness on $U$, but I am not sure if it is by mistake or by intention. Even for $U$ bounded, I think it is still not a compact embedding due to the Rellich–Kondrachov theorem (Evans section 5.7 Theorem 1).

Comment: To disprove compactness, you typically would construct a bounded sequence in $W^{1,p}(U)$ which does not possess any convergent subsequences in $L^{p^*}$. It is also clear that this sequence must be unbounded in $W^{1,q}(U)$ for all $q > p$.

Comment: @gerw I understand this, this is the requirement on $W^{1,p}(U)$ to be precompact in $L^{p^*}$. I am asking for possible guidelines/ideas on how  to construct a counterexample for that. What's the intuition of this problem?

Comment: Did you find something to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $u_n(x)=a_n (1-n|x|)$ if $|x|<1/n$ and $u_n(x)=0$ if $|x|\ge 1/n$ and show that you can take $a_n$ is such a way that the sequence in bounded in $W^{1,p}(B(0,1))$ but no subsequence converges in $L^{p^*}(B(0,1))$. So the idea is that the mass is concentrating at the origin.

Comment: If you take the $a_n=n^{\frac{d-p}{p}}$ then how can you calculate the Lp norm of a triangles of height 1 and base 1/n?